# Can someone explain why the active_file and inactive_file values are much greater than cache in my docker container's cgroup memory.stat file?

Tags: docker, memory, kubernetes, cgroups

Can anyone explain how it's possible `active_file` + `inactive_file` (~228MiB) is much greater than `cache` (~537KiB)?

My understanding is that `cache` should include `active_file` and `inactive_file`, so how can the `cache` value be so low?

Note:  These stats are from a container running fluentd in a kubernetes cluster, for streaming logs from all the pods in the node to aws cloudwatch, so there is a lot of file I/O going on with containers writing to the log files, and fluentd reading from the log files. (I wonder if this shared file access pattern has something to do with it...)

```
/sys/fs/cgroup/memory# cat memory.stat
cache 536576
rss 404602880
rss_huge 0
shmem 0
mapped_file 0
dirty 32768
writeback 0
swap 0
pgpgin 149468
pgpgout 50557
pgfault 904076
pgmajfault 0
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 176812032
inactive_file 216268800
active_file 12009472
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 419430400
hierarchical_memsw_limit 419430400
total_cache 536576
total_rss 404602880
total_rss_huge 0
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 0
total_dirty 32768
total_writeback 0
total_swap 0
total_pgpgin 149468
total_pgpgout 50557
total_pgfault 904076
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 176812032
total_inactive_file 216268800
total_active_file 12009472
total_unevictable 0
```

Comment: Could you point out any source where it is clearly said that `cache` should be equal to `active_file + inactive_file`. I checked it on a few different systems and those values are actually never equal. Sometimes sum of `active_file and inactive_file` is bigger than `cache` and other times is smaller. Here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/ they state that `The exact formula is cache = active_file + inactive_file + tmpfs. ` but I'm not sure if it always works like that. Have you tested it on your on-premise test environment, let's say `minikube` or `kubeadm set up cluster` ?

Comment: Hi @mario, and addition to the source you provided, I saw similar mentions at the following sources:
https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-monitor-docker-resource-metrics/  "cache memory reflects data stored on disk that is currently cached in memory. Cache can be further decomposed into active and inactive memory (active_file, inactive_file)"

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-memory.html "active_file + inactive_file = cache - size of tmpfs"

Comment: Seems like the only way that the equation would work out is if tmpfs can be a negative value, as both `inactive_file` and `active_file` each already exceed the value of `cache`.   I haven't tried on a local environment, but I'll give that a shot.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

MADV_FREE pages have been put into LRU_INACTIVE_FILE list since Linux v4.12.
See
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f7ad2a6cb9f7c4040004bedee84a70a9b985583e

LazyFree pages will be gone under memory pressure or `echo 0 > memory.force_empty`